# Python connecting to an HTTP server

Tags: python, http, dropbox

In my program, I am trying to access `https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token`. In order to do that, I was trying to use `http.client.HTTPSConnection()`. However, I am receiving a 400 statement from the server, even though when I send the same request through my browser, I get an actual response:

`{"error": "Call requires one of the following methods: POST, OPTIONS. Got GET."}`

I believe that this happens for subdomains, since I also tested the function for `https://docs.python.org/3/`, and the result is very similar.

Here is my code (Python3):

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('docs.python.org')
conn.request('get', '/3/')
response = conn.getresponse().read()
print(response)
```

How should I use the `http.client` library to send the proper request?

Comment: Try use an uppercase 'GET'?

Comment: @Philip Tzou I can't believe this actually fixed it! Please post is an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Might be worth to look at [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Change the lowercase 'get' to uppercase 'GET' should resolve the problem.

The reason: according to section 5.1.1, [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt):

> The Method token indicates the method to be performed on the
>   resource identified by the Request-URI. The method is case-sensitive.

RFC2616 also defined 8 methods which are "OPTIONS", "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE", and "CONNECT". All of them are uppercase.

We do know some HTTP clients like `python-requests` and `jQuery.ajax` also support lowercase methods but they are just not the standard way defined by the RFC for using those methods. To prevent issues, use uppercase ones first.

Comment: `requests` would be a more relevant lowercase example since this is a python question